# Discount for specific user group in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, users

I need to create 3 user groups and all of these groups must to have discount on all products in percent.

Example:

Group1 have discount of 10% on all products,
Group2 have discount of 13% on all products,
Group2 have discount of 16% on all products

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wait, wait, wait. That video tutorial referenced in the currently accepted answer is very outdated and unnecessary. All you need to do is create a new product pricing rule and use the "Multiply the unit price by some amount" line item action. Multiply it by .9 for a 10% discount, .87 for a 13%, and .84 for a 16% discount. Then just select the "Discount" price component (or else use a module to define a new price component type) in the action so it appears as expected in order total price breakdowns.

The only reason abusing the tax system was recommended at the time of that video recording was because you could not specify the price component type in the rules action. That has long since been changed, but alas the video still gets linked to quite a bit.

Comment: hmm, great i agree and upvoted, can you please provide with steps, sothat it will more clear and i want this to be as accepted answer

Comment: True, but it was enough, the rest I figured out...Thanks anyway...I'll accept this answer because it is more precise...

Comment: The steps are basically the first paragraph if you imagine the sentences being bullet points. : )

Answer (score 1):

Just add a product pricing rule with a user role condition, See this [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/22617715) for adding pricing rules.

Below are the steps to achieve discount for product pricing

- Go to `store-> Configuration-> taxes` and then  add a tax type.
- Name it something like "Discount Offer"
- And then Check the option "Display taxes of type inclusive in product prices" and  then save it.
- Go to tax rate tab and add the discount amount like "-0.10" and choose the type you created "Discount Offer" and save it.
- and then make a pricing rule for a user role condition.